# \mbox overfull in math environment

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, hyphenation, format

I am quite new to Latex and am having an Overfull \hbox warning on Overleaf with the following code in a document environment:

```
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{math}
l^*=\frac{l}{ke^{\tau\lambda}}=(\frac{1}{ke^{\tau\Delta}})(\frac{\lambda_a}{v})=\mbox{effective mean life of the neutrons from formation by fission to absorption or loss from pile by leakage.}
\end{math}
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should probably read a good introdution to latex, hardly anyone ever uses the `math` env.  Try https://www.learnlatex.org/. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Put the text outside the formula

Answer (score 1):

You can't have that long text in a formula: the text is outside the math. In any case, the contents of `\mbox` cannot be split across lines.

Two alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The formula $l^*=\frac{l}{ke^{\tau\lambda}}=(\frac{1}{ke^{\tau\Delta}})(\frac{\lambda_a}{v})$
represents the effective mean life of the neutrons from formation by fission to 
absorption or loss from pile by leakage.

\bigskip

The formula
\[
l^*=\frac{l}{ke^{\tau\lambda}}=\frac{1}{ke^{\tau\Delta}}\frac{\lambda_a}{v}
\]
represents the effective mean life of the neutrons from formation by fission to 
absorption or loss from pile by leakage.

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer the latter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When in inline math mode, it's advisable not to use `\frac` notation and, instead, to use inline-fraction notation. E.g., instead of `\frac{a}{b}`, write `a/b`.

You may further want to consider replacing `e^{\tau\lambda}` and `e^{\tau\Delta}` with `\exp(\tau\lambda)` and `\exp(\tau\Delta)`, respectively.

Either way, whenever possible, use natural words rather than terse but stilted math notation.

The outcome of applying the first suggestion is shown in the middle paragraph below. The outcome of applying both suggestion is shown in the bottom paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$l^*=\frac{l}{ke^{\tau\lambda}}=(\frac{1}{ke^{\tau\Delta}})(\frac{\lambda_a}{v})$ is the effective mean life of the neutrons from formation by fission to absorption or loss from pile by leakage.

\bigskip
$l^*=l/(ke^{\tau\lambda})=(ke^{\tau\Delta})^{-1}(\lambda_a/v)$ is the effective mean life of the neutrons from formation by fission to absorption or loss from pile by leakage.

\bigskip
$l^*=l/(k\exp(\tau\lambda))=(k\exp(\tau\Delta))^{-1}(\lambda_a/v)$ is the effective mean life of the neutrons from formation by fission to absorption or loss from pile by leakage.

\end{document}
```